# Django CustomTags Using Session

Tags: django, session, django-custom-tags

I'm trying to use ***Django*** to output an HTML page based on whether the session is set or not.

when I submit my Django Form (via my view) I set the session like this:

---

```
def index(request):
    users = Users.objects.all()
    totalUsers = len(users)
    form = CreateUserForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        form = CreateUserForm()
    context = {
        "form": form,
        'users': users,
        "totalUsers": totalUsers,
    }
    request.session.set_expiry(300)
    request.session['loggedIn'] = True
    return render(request, 'SmartCity/index.html', context)
```

---

I know this is successful because I can see the value set in the DB.

In my CustomTags.py file, I want to more or less check the session variable "loggedIn" is set, and if it is, return one thing, otherwise, return something else. This is how I thought to achieve it, but it's not working:

---

```
from Django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('SmartCity/index.html', takes_context=True)
    def hello_world(context):
        request = context['request']
        loggedInStatus = request.session.get('logged_in', 'False')
        if loggedInStatus == True:
            return "Hello world"
```

*The error I receive is:*
https://preview.ibb.co/dqAe8k/2017_09_19_18_06_57.png

I could totally be on the wrong track... I would appreciate any advice you might be able to give a Django beginner :)

Comment: you can print what the output of `print(context)`

Comment: Why are you doing any of this? Django includes a full authentication framework, you shouldn't be attempting to manage logged-in status yourself via the session.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm a new Django user, so I've got no idea what's really included in the framework - I'm still thinking in PHP. Could you possibly point me in the right direction on how I'd do this using the built in authentication?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/